# array_splice with multidimensional array breaks inserted array

Tags: php

I have the following array structure:

```
$tpl = [
    'breadcrumbs' => [
        [ 'title' => 'Item Database', 'text' => 'Item Database', 'url' => SITE_DOMAIN.ADMIN_PATH.'/items/' ],
        [ 'title' => $category->name, 'text' => $category->name, 'active' => true ]
    ]
];
```

I am attempting to insert an element **before** the last element, so thought I could use `array_splice` as follows:

```
if( !is_null($category->category) )
{
    array_splice(
        $tpl['breadcrumbs'],
        1,
        0,
        [ 'title' => $category->category->name, 'text' => $category->category->name, 'url' => SITE_DOMAIN.ADMIN_PATH.'/items/' ]
    );
}
```

However, this seems to flatten the item I am trying to insert (as per the expected behaviour) and produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Item Database
            [text] => Item Database
            [url] => https://local/qmdepot/admin/items/
        )

    [1] => Medical Department
    [2] => Medical Department
    [3] => https://local/qmdepot/admin/items/
    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Class 1
            [text] => Class 1
            [active] => 1
        )

)
```

While the expected output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Item Database
            [text] => Item Database
            [url] => https://local/qmdepot/admin/items/
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Medical Department
            [text] => Medical Department
            [url] => https://local/qmdepot/admin/items/
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Class 1
            [text] => Class 1
            [active] => 1
        )
)
```

I am able to achieve this using the following code, but it feels a little hacky to me:

```
# Set up the breadcrumbs:
if( !is_null($category->category) )
{
    $tpl['breadcrumbs'][2] = $tpl['breadcrumbs'][1];
    $tpl['breadcrumbs'][1] = [ 'title' => $category->category->name, 'text' => $category->category->name, 'url' => SITE_DOMAIN.ADMIN_PATH.'/items/' ];
}
```

Is there any way to insert an array item into a multi-dimensional array at a specified index without writing a custom function or using the hack above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the item you want to insert is an array, and `array_splice` takes an array of items, put your array in an array.

Also since you want to insert something before the last element you can use a negative number for the offset to count backward from the end. (The effect is the same with the data you've got, but matters on arrays of different sizes.)

```
array_splice(
    $tpl['breadcrumbs'],
    -1,
    0,
    [[ 'title' => $category->category->name, 'text' => $category->category->name, 'url' => SITE_DOMAIN.ADMIN_PATH.'/items/' ]]
);
```